# Authenticate with a Rails app?

Tags: users, api, authentication

There seems to be lots of posts where another app / website uses a WP website to authenticate against. I am looking for the opposite.

I have a Rails app that uses Devise for authentication. I have a WP site hosted on a separate server. This will be a support site for the Rails app. I want the support site to be closed unless you have authenticated on the rails site.

I don't think I would have a problem creating an API on the Rails app I just don't have enough experience with WP to integrate the two together like this.

In the end what I want is if you are authenticated on the Rails app you can access the WP site and are automatically logged in / authenticated etc. otherwise you get redirect to the Rails app login page.

I am looking for help (plugin, suggestions, tutorial etc.) on how to configure WP to allow this or else confirm that this is not really practical to accomplish.

Comment: This sounds like a broad question that will get you a broad answer. Can you be more specific about what is it that you need help with, general strategy, specific code, something else?

Comment: Agreed - updated to hopefully a more specific question.